# How much a 2000 lei romanian bill is worth

Tags: paper-money

How much is the special edition 1999 Romanian total solar eclipse 2,000 Lei bill worth in today’s currecny (USD)? Thank you!

Comment: Questions about collectible notes or coins are off topic here. From our point of view a 2,000 Lei bill is worth 2,000 Lei.

Answer (score 1):

Less than a nickel. 2000/10000/4.039 = 0.04951720723

Comment: One sentence unsupported answers are **very** frowned upon. Please add a citation.

Comment: The Lei was adjusted by 10000x in 2005 (that is why Mike divided by 10000). In any case, this bill was intended to be a novelty collectors item, it never had much face value.